# Creating an ok/cancel modal popup for menu items

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I have an index page below and I have a div pageContent which is used as a container for
3 different partial pages. There is a default partial page that loads. 
Here is my code for the index page

```
        @model Solution.Model.Projectstatusviewmodel

        <div id="ProjID">
            <div id="pjls">
                <label for="SelectProjID">Project:</label>
                @Html.DropDownList("mydrp", Model.ProjectsInfoSelectList, Model.SelectedProject, new { id = "", @class = "yel", @onchange = "javascript:GetStatusDate(this.value);" })
            </div>   
        </div>
            <ul id="menu">
                    <li class="clLink1">@Html.ActionLink("link1", "link1method", "Home")</li>
                    <li class="clLink2">@Html.ActionLink("link2", "link2method", "Home")</li>
                    <li class="clLink3">@Html.ActionLink("link3", "link3method", "Home")</li>
                </ul>

        <div id="pageContent"></div>
```

Here is the code that handles the different navigation

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
                    //Prepare the partial views. When page loads display the first partial view as default
                    //then process others.
                    $(function () {
                        //Load the first link's content on document ready
                        var firstLinkHref = $("#menu li a:first").eq(0).attr("href");
                        $("#pageContent").load(firstLinkHref);

                        $("#menu li a").click(function (e) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            $("#pageContent").load($(this).attr("href"));
                        });
                    });
                });
```

Problem: I have a form in the partial page that loads as default. When users complete this 
form and click on the second or third link, I want users to get a prompt to save their work
otherwise everything is lost. It will be more of a Ok/Cancel alert box.

How can I acheive that here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have an id on the form and have a confirm dialog to warn the user that he should save or the data would be lost:

```
<form id="firstPage">
...

$("#menu li a").click(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var firstForm = $('#firstPage');
    var shouldContinue = true;

    if(firstForm.length > 0)
    {
        shouldContinue = confirm("All the data that is not saved will be lost.Do you want to proceed ? ");
    }

    if(shouldContinue){
        $("#pageContent").load($(this).attr("href"));
    }
});
```

This would work if you want to warn the user, when he is navigated from the first form to the rest of the partial views.

Also why don't you just switch between your partial views, but use links ?
You can have a function to replace the partial view container with the new information:

```
$('.links').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 

    var firstForm = $('#firstPage');
    var shouldContinue = true;

    if(firstForm.length > 0)
    {
        shouldContinue = confirm("All the data that is not saved will be lost.Do you want to proceed ? ");
    }

    if(shouldContinue){
        var $pageContent= $('#pageContent'),
        url = $(this).data('url');

        $.get(url, function(data) {
            $pageContent.replaceWith(data);
        });
    }
}
```

and have on your page:

```
<button class="links" data-url='@Url.Action("link1method","Home")>Link1</button>
<button class="links" data-url='@Url.Action("link2method","Home")>Link2</button>
<button class="links" data-url='@Url.Action("link3method","Home")>Link3</button>
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try this and get back to you.

Comment: It works great. Please explain this "if(firstForm.length > 0)" . what are you trying to test here?

Comment: i check if we have the first form element in the DOM ;]

Comment: quick question for you. Looking at your example with links that you suggested, Is it possible to pass parameters to the partial pages? Thanks

Comment: I tried the second piece of the code with links and it is only the first partial view that gets loaded. The others do not get loaded

Comment: Yes the $pageContent.replaceWith(data) was returning undefined but replaced with $pageContent.html(data); and this works well now.